# Problema en Login con Servicio Web en aplicación de Android

Tags: android, sql, webservice, mvc

Al crear una aplicación de android, al presionar el botón iniciar sesión no hace nada.

El servicio web al probarlo en [postman](/questions/tagged/postman) me devuelve el arreglo, este lo tengo subido en [azure](/questions/tagged/azure).

http://examenrestwebapi251955201320190401082959.azurewebsites.net/api/Login?USUARIO=edson&CONTRASENIA=123

y este es el arreglo que devuelve:

```
{"Table":[{"ID_USUARIO":1,"USUARIO":"edson","CONTRASENIA":"123","TIPO":1}]}
```

En el Logcat me muestra lo siguiente, que es lo único que logro identificar

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for ID_USUARIO
```

En mi actividad tengo el siguiente código y estoy utilizando el loopj:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(edtUsuario.getText().toString().isEmpty() || edtContra.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Hay Campos En Blanco!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                edtUsuario.setText("");
                edtContra.setText("");
            }else{
                String usu = edtUsuario.getText().toString().replace(" ","%20");
                String pas = edtContra.getText().toString().replace(" ","%20");
                String url = "http://examenrestwebapi251955201320190401082959.azurewebsites.net/api/Login?USUARIO="+usu+"&CONTRASENIA="+pas;
                cliente.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        if(statusCode == 200) {
                            String respuesta = new String(responseBody);
                            if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error De Usuario y/o Contraseña!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                edtUsuario.setText("");
                                edtContra.setText("");
                            } else {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(respuesta);

                                    Usuario u = new Usuario();
                                    u.setId_usuario(jsonObj.getInt("ID_USUARIO"));
                                    u.setUsuario(jsonObj.getString("USUARIO"));
                                    u.setContraseña(jsonObj.getString("CONTRASENIA"));
                                    u.setTipo(jsonObj.getInt("TIPO"));
                                    Intent i = null;
                                    switch(u.getTipo()){
                                        case 1:
                                            u.setNom_tipo("Administrador");
                                            i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ActivityConsultaVin.class);
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            u.setNom_tipo("Usuario");
                                            i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ActivityConsultaVin.class);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    i.putExtra("u",u);
                                        startActivity(i);


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error Desconocido. Intentelo De Nuevo!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edtUsuario.setText("");
                        edtContra.setText("");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Espero poder contar con el apoyo de ustedes, ya que soy nuevo en esto de Android y WS, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que observar la estructura de tu respuesta y comprenderla para saber cómo leerla.

En la respuesta tenemos esto:

```
{"Table":[{"ID_USUARIO":1,"USUARIO":"edson","CONTRASENIA":"123","TIPO":1}]}
```

Si lo analizamos, eso es:

- Un `JSONObject` cuya clave es `Table` ... `{"Table": [] }`
- Ese `JSONObject` contiene a su vez un `JSONArray` con otro `JSONObject` dentro con sus datos apareados mediante clave:valor ... `{"ID_USUARIO:1 ...}`

Sabiendo eso, para la lectura, tienes que:

1. Sacar el `JSONArray` que hay en el `JSONObject` con la clave `Table`
2. Sacar el `JSONObject` que hay en el índice `0` del `JSONArray` obtenido en (1). Si fuesen varios objetos JSON habría que abrir un bucle para leerlos.

Aplicando esto el código sería:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(respuesta);
    try{
            JSONArray  jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Table");   //(1)
            JSONObject jsonData  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);      //(2)
            Usuario u = new Usuario();
            u.setId_usuario(jsonData.getInt("ID_USUARIO"));
            u.setUsuario(jsonData.getString("USUARIO"));
            u.setContraseña(jsonData.getString("CONTRASENIA"));
            u.setTipo(jsonData.getInt("TIPO"));
            //... Resto del código
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Haciéndolo así debería funcionar, dando por hecho que la respuesta se recibe de la manera que indicas, y que la misma es de tipo `String`.

**NOTA:**

Para entender un JSON y en consecuencia saber cómo leerlo, lo básico es que sepas que, **todo lo que esté rodeado por `{ }` es un `JSONObject` y que todo lo que esté rodeado por `[]` es un `JSONArray`**. En el caso de los `JSONArray`, para obtener lo que haya dentro de ellos, tienes que usar **un índice**, sea de manera directa (como hicimos aquí, porque tenía un solo elemento) o mediante un bucle.

Partiendo de ahí, según la estructura, puede haber `JSONObject` dentro de `JSONArray` o viceversa. O puede haber `JSONArray` que tengan dentro otros `JSONArray` anidados, o `JSONObject` que tengan otros `JSONObject` anidados. Poco importa, una vez hayas aprendido a analizar el objeto, sabiendo lo que significa `{}` y lo que significa `[]`.

Comment: Me ha funcionado correctamente, te agradezco por la cátedra amigo, lo tomaré muy en cuenta de hoy adelante.